# Making an asterisk in a label red

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have the following .html markup

### .html

```
    <paper-button
        raised
        active
        toggles
        on-tap = "toggler"
        class = "bold">Patient *
      <iron-icon
          icon = ""
          id = "fe-icon"></iron-icon>
    </paper-button>
  </div>
```

How can I make the * in Patient * red without the entire label being red, and also make the asterisk larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it with a `<span>` like `>Patient <span class="asterisk">*</span></iron-icon>` then you can style it individually.